# Designing {classes} in Ruby (on Rails)

Tags: ruby, class

I am experimenting a project which grabs product data from retailer web sites using Nokogiri. There are more than 500 retailers and their site structure including page structure are very different to each other.

My initial thoughts were to create one class for each retailer (site) so that any changes can be adopted easily. But I am not sure if each class are to be 'required' (loaded/unloaded) explicitly and would it result in too much performance issues.

Comment: Ruby allows us to dynamically overwrite classes and methods. `load` will load a file every time you request it, not just the first time which `require` would do. Put those behaviors together and you'll be on your way to dynamically loading the code specific to a particular site on demand, overwriting the previously loaded code. Ruby's garbage collection should reclaim any memory made available when the class is overwritten. Try that, and if it doesn't work as you expect, edit your question *with the code and results* and we'll go from there.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is nothing to be concerned of. It is better to preload them in prod env once. They will certainly eat up some memory. But 500 classes is not that many so I think you'll be good.

Comment: I'd second this. You can easily `require` a whole directory with `Dir["retailers/*.rb"].each {|file| require file }`.

Comment: Are there any DRY way of specifying the differences between sites? Because the actions are going to be the same. Would a hash for each site make better design and sense? Something like `site_1 = { :product => "//*[(@id=\"products\")]", :product_detail => "..."}` and so on.

Comment: You surely can build some kind of inheritance hierarchy for individual scrapers. And you might be good with just keeping different xpath selectors. However, in my experience, usually scraping of multiple sites is not that simple as specifying different xpath selectors. Usually one have to implement some kind of a custom non-typical scraping logic for some of the sites. So, being able to hook into different parts of the scraping logic is a must-have feature. And this is exactly the place where object hierarchy comes to the stage.

Comment: +1 @cryo28. Every site is different. Even if the HTML was a template, the content desired could require different selectors and adding the code intelligence to select the appropriate ones could result in a lot of wasted space. Ruby has ways of overwriting methods and classes so it's not necessary to load 500 classes that aren't being used. See my comment to the original question for more info.